# What does "error: ’myfn’ declared as function returning a function" mean?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I am trying to write a function that returns a function pointer.  Here is my minimal example:

```
void (*myfn)(int)()  // Doesn't work: supposed to be a function called myfn
{                    // that returns a pointer to a function returning void
}                    // and taking an int argument.
```

When I compile this with `g++ myfn.cpp` it prints this error:

```
myfn.cpp:1:19: error: ‘myfn’ declared as function returning a function
myfn.cpp:1:19: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

Does this mean I am not allowed to return a function pointer?

Comment: Is that really your minimal example? In the code above, you define a function that returns a function, but then you don't actually return anything, is that why you're getting the error?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths yes, that is a real program and the real output.  I guess g++ fails before it validates things like that.  If I write a more complete program I get the same message.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. With gcc 4.7.2, after correcting the definition of `retfn` to `void retfn(int n)`, your longer example compiles just fine under both C and C++ without the error you're getting.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths the code in my question does not mention retfn.  The code in the question is the whole file myfn.cpp.  There is nothing else.  The code in the answer works as expected.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are allowed to return a function pointer, and the correct syntax looks like this:

```
void (*myfn())(int)
{
}
```

Complete example:

```
#include <cstdio>

void retfn(int) {
    printf( "retfn\n" );
}

void (*callfn())(int) {
    printf( "callfn\n" );
    return retfn;
}

int main() {
    callfn()(1); // Get back retfn and call it immediately
}
```

Which compiles and runs like this:

```
$ g++ myfn.cpp && ./a.out
callfn
retfn
```

If anyone has a good explanation for why g++'s error message suggests this is not possible, I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: This is what `typedef`'s are for. I would deny anyone from checking in code like this with great vengeance and furious anger.

Comment: Agreed - I would always use a typedef.

Comment: @GManNickG: The problem with using a `typedef` is that it can hide some information that would be useful. For example, assume `typedef void retfn(int); ... retfn *myfn(void) {...}`. The typedef `retfn` doesn't tell me what the pointed-to function returns, or what parameters it takes, or that it's even *callable* ("fn" may be obvious to me, but not someone else). If the typedef is in a header somewhere, I have to go look it up to get that info. I'd rather have that information up front. I've cooled on typedefs for this reason.

Comment: I will say that `callfn()(1);` is just bad manners; you could at least assign the result of `callfn` to a temporary and call through that temporary (especially if `callfn` can potentially return `NULL`).

Comment: @JohnBode: You're only switching from "You'd have to look at the typedef" to "you'll need to look at the function", as far as I can tell. What's the difference? That's what descriptive names are for, anyway. `typedef void disconnect_callback_function(); disconnect_callback_function get_disconnect_callback_function();`

Comment: @GManNickG: The difference is that `void (*get_disconnect_callback_function())(void)` gives me all the information I need up front.  I know that it not only returns a pointer to a function, I know that the pointed-to function returns `void` and takes `void` as a parameter list, and I get all of that from that one prototype.  No need to look anywhere else.

Comment: @JohnBode I guess the fact that I felt the need to add a comment suggests I felt I was being a little rude :)

Comment: g++'s error message is partially correct. You cannot return a function (or an array) from a function, only a _pointer_ to an array or a function. It's seems that `myfn` is declared in the question to be a _pointer_ to a function returning a function (bad) taking `int` returning another function (bad, again) taking no arguments. Of course, you cannot provide a function body as definition to a pointer to function but perhaps g++ didn't get as far as that error.

Comment: @CharlesBailey thanks, that helps explain the message from g++.

Comment: I will +1, if you add an example with typedef. The syntax without a typedef looks awful.